# Is there a way to remove hair particles in particle edit mode?

Tags: particles

Is there some way to fully remove hair particles (e.g. with a brush) while in particle edit mode?

Ideally this would actually remove the particle, **instead of e.g. making it tiny with the cut brush**. The problem with cutting particles until they are invisible is that they will still affect child particles:

[image]

The above example uses interpolated child particles.

[**Blendfile**](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/28121)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can select the hair particles and press <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Delete</kbd>.

---

*To give credit where credit is due, thanks to Dan Eicher for pointing this out on the developer mailing list.*

---

There does not seem to be a brush for doing this, but you can use circle select (<kbd>C</kbd>) to select hair particles with a brush.

Answer (score 0):

in particle edit on the side there is comb smooth add length puff cut weight at the top of that list there is none this works like edit mode you can gather vertices and stuff and even delete stuff just click on one and click delete also on the bottom of the screen a little past the global thing there is a particle display mode click on either three and you will have more options to play with in none mode (= hope this helps